# How to join(nest) django apps in site

Tags: django

Last time i make my way through python library - django. I have idea how MVC model works and other basics about creating django projects. I'm going to create site in django but there is one thing that loom large in my mind.
After i will create apps for managing articles, polls, and other likely to change content of site, i have to join it together on one page. By lack of knowledge it looks awful for me.

To make index page, i mind to create app and connect it in URLconf to `'^$'`. Then, i will have large template containing everything in html - head, meta, includes(js, css) etc. It doesn't sounds good for me(probably lack of knowledge). Look..

How i will be able to get link to specific content on site(i.e. article) to give it to somebody? I need */article/2013/02/55* show specific article but it needs to use my index page for meta, includes, entire structure of site etc. I can't imagine how I will be able to connect it together.

I'm in the course of "The Definitive Guide to Django: Web Development Done Right" book. Maybe i will get answer later but I'm nervous and impatient. It would be great to make use of ajax and some jquery-ui on site but i can't even imagine how to do static site with nested apps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to [extend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#extends) the base template and use blocks.

## base.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>...</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="...">
    <script>...</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  {% block content %}
    Content from the base template
  {% endblock content %}
  </body>
</html>
```

## appname/templatename.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  Content from the app template to replace other content 
{% endblock content %}
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) for more info on template inheritance.