# How do you nest in Django Templates?

Tags: php, python, html, django

I am trying to Migrate a PHP based website into Python with Django as a framework.

However I'm having real issues with the template. I can't seem to get my head around how they work in terms of structure.

By this I am referring "nesting", using different pages to build a template as done in PHP. Take the following for example -

index.php -

```
<html>  
<head>      
    <title>Home | Sequence Control Panel</title>
    <?php require_once "head.php"; ?>
</head>     
    <body>          
        <!-- Header -->             
            <?php require_once "nav.php"; ?>

        <p>Hello World</p>

        <!-- Footer -->
            <?php require_once "footer.php"; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

footer.php -

```
<footer id="footer">
<ul class="icons">
    <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-dribbble"><span class="label">Dribbble</span></a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="icon fa-envelope-o"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="copyright">
    <li>&copy; <?= date('Y'); ?> Sequence CP</li><li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
</ul>
```

Essentially, I'm splitting the footer, head and nav in three different pages and linking back to them.

How does one link the contents of multiple pages to one page as I have done above with index.php and footer.php using `<?php require_once "footer.php"; ?>`

I'm aware that I could use -

```
{% block content %}

    <p>Hello World</p>

{% endblock content %}
```

but I can only do it once in my template. I cannot seem to be able to use `block content` more than once.

How does one nest contents of multiple pages as opposed to just one?

PS: I'm new to Django

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join(nest) django apps in site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782572/how-to-joinnest-django-apps-in-site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django has an [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#include) template tag that allows you load other templates (like header and footer) in your current template and render them with the `context`:

```
{% include "header.html" %}

{% include "footer.html" %}
```